# Can I disable the Review Icon

Tags: feature-request, review

The Review Icon came to my screen about a week ago. I find that it is promoting 100 or more new posts every day.

By the time I see this, I have seen the posts already as I tend to look through posts and see whether or not I can assist.

Can I disable this Icon?   Thank you

Comment: Is simply ignoring the button not an option? I suppose you could use a userscript to hide it...

Comment: Do you just want to hide the red, or the button entirely?

Comment: If you absolutely want it gone we could try banning you from review completely. Not sure if/how it would work and seems like a sledgehammer to crack a nut....

Comment: Just curious as I haven't tried myself but, can it not just be blocked with something like uBlock Origin? Essentially it just sets it's CSS selector as `display: none;`

Comment: @Mokubai Pinging you for ^ comment.

Comment: The ban is specific to the review queues and I don't believe it affects anything else. It is normally applied automatically after repeatedly failing review audits but can be applied manually if we notice a robo-reviewer or someone making consistently bad reviews in general. From what I can tell you simply get a "there is nothing for you to review" message. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/303584/new-review-navigation-does-not-tell-review-banned-users-what-happened-or-why

Comment: While I did mention it, I'd very much prefer *not* to use the ban except as a last resort. Review is a good place for you to see and act on both good and bad questions and answers. You can also see how other users voted and how/if their actions differed from yours by using the history. As mentioned removing the ability to review is an option, but not one to be taken lightly. A ban can be any number of days up to a year.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the following custom stylesheet to hide just the red alert indicator:

```
.js-review-button._danger-indicator:after {
    display: none
}
```

or hide the entire button:

```
.js-review-button {
    display: none
}
```

This can be created using a custom stylesheet addon like Stylish. Define a new stylesheet (in Stylish, via the triple-dot menu into Create New Style) and apply it to the following domains (in Stylish, via "Applies to" => "Specify"):

```
askubuntu.com
mathoverflow.net
onstartups.com
serverfault.com
stackapps.com
stackexchange.com
stackoverflow.com
superuser.com
```

It is not necessary to allow Stylish to autodiscover new styles; just click Cancel when it prompts you.

GIF of the process (click for full size):

[image: GIF of process]

Comment: @John If you install a userscript extension (Violentmonkey, Tampermonkey), you should be able to create a new script in one of them and copy-paste the script in and save. Alternatively, you can save the file with the extension `.user.js` and open it in the browser (after you have one of those extensions installed). Or [use this raw gist link](https://gist.github.com/BobVul/151e52547244ce9f9f47c2434d75b5df/raw/SEHideReviewIndicator.user.js).

Comment: @John I assume the banned comment was meant to be a response to Mokubai on the question?

Comment: lol, "ViolentMonkey".

Comment: @John I'm not sure what you mean by constant red icon/flashing red; I don't see that happen. If you would like to discuss bans from review you'd need to ping (`@` notify) Mokubai in the comments on your question; as they've not commented on this answer they won't get notified of your comments here.

Comment: @John Ok, I see what you mean. I've updated this answer with a pure CSS approach that should apply instantly (and therefore not flash anything on/off), if you would like to use that instead. To get in contact with Mokubai, you can simply reply to their comment on your question above ^ since they have commented there, they will be pingable. Just not in the answer comments because they have not commented here. Use the ping format of `@` followed by the username (username alone will not notify), as I have done to you at the beginning of this comment.

Comment: @John Alternatively, you can contact them [in the Ask A Super User Moderator chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/114/ask-a-super-user-moderator), just ping them in the same format (`@` + `Mokubai`) as they will be in that room.

Comment: @John Your comment was missing the `@` ping so they would not have gotten the notification. That's why I mentioned it again.

Comment: @John FWIW I've added a GIF (video) of the process for adding that CSS block to this answer. If you'd rather not go to that trouble that's fine too.

Comment: @John I've also added an alternative that should hide the entire button. The new indicator hide will not flicker so it's up to you which one (if any) you use. If you really prefer userscripts I suppose I could wrap these up as one...

Comment: On Firefox, this worked with Stylus